# Reverse proxy error when I receive gzip data

Tags: c#, sockets

I have made a reverse proxy in C# when I receive gzip data and forward it to the client it doesn't seem to understand it.

```
The webpage at http://m.agar.io/findServer might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

The server sends:

```
[tcpFowarderStream] >> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 29 Nov 2015 15:39:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://agar.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 24cf6816767d34ee-LHR
Content-Encoding: gzip

79
▼      ♥?V?,P?R245??0????35?2450R?Q*??N?S?RJ?(?
2(t??M4.1Jt????()K?)?I?34M?((♀2???t?
??L?????p3N3??N1??N?0?T?♣   ??

[tcpFowarderStream] >> a
♥ ??e`i
0
```

Could somebody explain why this happens and help provide a solution? It works fine for other websites only this website screws up.

Response without a proxy:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 29 Nov 2015 17:03:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://agar.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 24cfe2aa70ea34b2-LHR
Content-Encoding: gzip

79
        V ,P R245Գ0г  37 2450R Q*  N S RJ ( 
2( t  M4 1Nt ȉ ()K ) I 34M ((2 ˶t 
  L  Ȏ p3N3  L  M H T      
a
 7~Y(i   
0
```

Comment: I have also tried changing the encoding to ASCII and UTF8 to no avail.

Comment: What happens when you directly visit the website without a proxy, does it load properly then?  The server indicates correctly the `Content-Encoding` as `gzip`, if you forward everything 1:1 there should be no problems. Can you compare the input and output streams of your proxy, and see if they exactly match up?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the response they match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I changed it to use Encoding.Default.